# paste0: could not allocate memory (0 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'

Tags: r, memory-management, paste, gsub

When creating INSERT statements (for Impala SQL)

```
INSERT INTO table (`field1`,...`field100`) VALUES
 ("column1", "column2", 0.001, 1, NULL, ..., 1, NULL), # Loop over inserted lines and columns
 ("column1", "column2", 0.001, 1, NULL, ..., 1, NULL), 
...
 ("column1", "column2", 0.001, 1, NULL, ..., 1, NULL);
```

from a table read from csv file

```
MyData <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/user/R/file.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
```

I concatenate the insert string in order to ensure that the data types are put to the insert statement correctly. The length of the strings become finally around 50 - 100 kB. I typically run several thousand such inserts without problems.

However, when fixing the data types I occasionnally end up having errors. For example, when converting numbers to strings:

```
# Error in paste0(s, as.character(elem), ",") : 
#  could not allocate memory (0 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'
```

Or when converting `NA`s to `NULL`s.

```
# Error in paste0(s, "NULL,") : 
#  could not allocate memory (0 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'
```

In the above errors `s` is the string concatenated by using `paste0`.

Although not related, I ended up another issue (similar?) with `gsub`:

```
Error in gsub("\\n", " ", sqls) : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (132871 of 1 bytes)
```

I do have about 1.38 Gb memory reserved (seen with Windows Task Manager), and during execution memory usage of R does not exceed about 1.4 Gb. There is still plenty memory to be reserved. I tried to force garbage collection

```
# Try gargabe collection to prevent memory allocation errors:
gc()
gcinfo(verbose=FALSE)
```

But it did not help with the memory issues, because the error was not due to not enough memory.

The above errors I got with `R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)` (i386, mingw32). I tried also `R version 3.6.1` (i386, mingw32), but got similar error:

```
Error in paste0(substr(s, 1, nchar(s) - 1), "),") : 
  could not allocate memory (0 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'
```

So updating R version is not a solution, memory consumption seems to be now, according to Windows task manager, almost double than with 3.5.3, around 2.66 Gb.

Comment: Please show what you are doing. What specifically do you do when you "fix the data types"? Why do you get an error involving `paste0` during this step? Also, what does "I do have about 1.38 Gb memory *reserved*" mean exactly?

Comment: Attempting to mind-read some context, I'd say there is some csv of data, and OP needs to read the column types and paste them together to form a SQL statement with types modified to fit their database (hence converting NA to NULL). But there is a great deal of context needed (what is the csv structure and size? what SQL flavour is needed and hence what type conversions? what is minimal example that throws error?)

Comment: Also, if you are trying to insert the data from the CSV in line by line and there is a lot I could easily see you hitting limits on string length if not total working memory. Easiest test is to see if it works on less data...

Comment: CVS structure contains over 100 columns, 5 of them are strings, other are numbers. There are more than 1 million lines in the CVS structure read to memory.

Comment: What is the limit of string length? I insert the data by chuncks, so the string length does not become more than about 100 000 characters long.

Comment: I tried to edit the question to describe the problem more.

Comment: There are closing votes that this problem is not well reproducible. That is true, but I wanted to post the question anyway to document the errors.

Comment: I'm not a database expert but what you are doing looks crazy inefficient to me ... There must be a better approach.

Comment: I agree that this is a brute force approach to load the contents of a CSV file via internet into a database to which one has rights only to "create table" and "insert into", and not rights simply to upload a full csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could run my script without such memory allocation errors by using `R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)` for `x86_64, mingw32` system. So  I could run the whole R script generating and running over 10 000 insert query chunks without problems using 64 bit R.

I had hesitated to change to 64 bit R, because some Java based ODBC drivers needed 32-bit drivers. But at least the hive-jdbc-uber driver which I needed in this case, worked together with 64-bit Java and 64-bit R.